# Form won't work inside table

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I'm producing a table from a php file through AJAX and showing it on an html page.
I want to be able to edit a row and change some values to my database. Although i make a form for each `<tr>` it won't seem to work and on submit it does nothing. (I know this is probably not the best way to approach this. Any suggestions would be appreciated.)

php code

```
if($_GET['function']=="editteam")
{
    $sql=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM tbl_Team")
    or die(mysql_error());

    echo '<table border="1"><thead><tr><th>Team Name</th><th>Location</th><th>Edit</th></tr></thead>';
    while($row=mysql_fetch_array($sql))
    {
        echo '<tr>';
        echo '<td>'.$row['team_name'].'</td>';
        echo '<td>'.$row['team_location'].'</td>';
        echo '<td><button class="shownextrow">Edit</button></td>';
        echo '</tr>';   
        echo '<form action="editteam.php" method="post">';  
        echo '<tr style="display:none" bgcolor="#FF0000">'; 
        echo '<td><input type="text" name="team_name" value="'.$row['team_name'].'"></td>';
        echo '<td><input type="text" name="team_location" value="'.$row['team_location'].'"></td>';
        echo '<td><input type="hidden" name="team_id" value="'.$row['team_id'].'"><input type="submit" value="Ok"></td>';
        echo '</tr>';
        echo '</form>';

    }       
    echo '</table>';

}
```

JS to show the next row (the editable one on click)

```
$(function() {
    $('.editteam').on('click', '.shownextrow', function() { 
      $(this).closest("tr").next().show();
    });
});
```

Comment: you should put your form in `<td>form here</td>`

Comment: you should put the form outside the table `<form><table>...</table></form>`

Comment: Or you can use jquery ajax.

Comment: How is my html invalid?

Comment: you need to put <form> tag inside tr

Comment: place form on <td> or create 1 form out of the table and change input hidden and submit in creating many form heavy page!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

```
if($_GET['function']=="editteam")
{
    $sql=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM tbl_Team")
    or die(mysql_error());

    echo '<table border="1"><thead><tr><th>Team Name</th><th>Location</th><th>Edit</th></tr></thead>';
    while($row=mysql_fetch_array($sql))
    {
        echo '<tr>';
            echo '<td>'.$row['team_name'].'</td>';
            echo '<td>'.$row['team_location'].'</td>';
            echo '<td><button class="shownextrow">Edit</button></td>';
        echo '</tr>';   

        echo '<tr style="display:none" bgcolor="#FF0000">'; 
            echo '<td colspan="3">';
                echo '<form action="editteam.php" method="post">';  
                    echo '<table>';
                    echo '<tr>';
                        echo '<td><input type="text" name="team_name" value="'.$row['team_name'].'"></td>';
                        echo '<td><input type="text" name="team_location" value="'.$row['team_location'].'"></td>';
                        echo '<td><input type="hidden" name="team_id" value="'.$row['team_id'].'"><input type="submit" value="Ok"></td>';
                    echo '</tr>';
                    echo '</table>';

                echo '</form>';
            echo '</td>';
        echo '</tr>';


    }       
    echo '</table>';

}
```

EDIT: Was missing a `/`

Comment: This should get me going, it only displays the first result from DB and the others on click but i'll work on it and fix this. Thank you

Comment: One of the tables did not close properly. Should be `</table>`.
Works like a charm.

Answer (score 2):

This will fix it, putting the form outside the table.

```
if($_GET['function']=="editteam")
{
    $sql=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM tbl_Team")
    or die(mysql_error());

    echo '<form action="editteam.php" method="post"><table border="1"><thead><tr><th>Team Name</th><th>Location</th><th>Edit</th></tr></thead>';
    while($row=mysql_fetch_array($sql))
    {
        echo '<tr>';
        echo '<td>'.$row['team_name'].'</td>';
        echo '<td>'.$row['team_location'].'</td>';
        echo '<td><button class="shownextrow">Edit</button></td>';
        echo '</tr>';   
        echo '<tr style="display:none" bgcolor="#FF0000">'; 
        echo '<td><input type="text" name="team_name" value="'.$row['team_name'].'"></td>';
        echo '<td><input type="text" name="team_location" value="'.$row['team_location'].'"></td>';
        echo '<td><input type="hidden" name="team_id" value="'.$row['team_id'].'"><input type="submit" value="Ok"></td>';
        echo '</tr>';

    }       
    echo '</table></form>';

}
```

Comment: I thought if that and tried it but when i click the Edit button to show the next row it takes it as submit i guess and gets me to editteam.php

Comment: Changed the "shownextrow" to button type but still now it returns and shows the last tr of the table that was printed out

Comment: That is a separate problem. Use jquery to help with that. `$("form button").click(function(e){e.preventDefault());`

Comment: I just don't understand why will it not create a form for each `<tr>`

Comment: Forms cannot be inside a table. If you want to have a form for each TR you need to nest the tables, putting a table in each cell and wrapping it with a form.

Answer (score 0):

Don't put `<form>` between `<table>` and `<tr>` or between `<tbody>` and `<tr>`. You can put it outside `<table>` or between `<tr>` and `<td>`.